# Assist with Magento 2.3.5 CSP (Magento_Csp) csp_whitelist.xml configuration - `style-src 'self'` entries reported

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, csp

I have followed documentation for setting up CSP whitelist using `csp_whitelist.xml` in a new module, but something is missing/not working as it should.

### Issue

I have 100s of `style-src 'self' 'report-sample'` errors in the console still after applying the module (see below).

Key notes: `report_only=0` as I understand should 'enforce' and not just report correct?

> **The console shows 'report-only'**

**Image 1 shows 'inline-style' errors for remote locations (from `elfsight.com` - WhatsApp chat)**
[image: Image report information]

**Image 2 shows 'inline-styles' for the 'local domain (Magento 2 site)'
[image]

`module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <module name="Vendor_MagentoCspGloSiteWhitelist" setup_version="1.0.0">
          <sequence>
               <module name="Magento_Csp"/>
          </sequence>
     </module>
</config>
```

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
     <default>
          <csp>
               <mode>
                    <storefront>
                         <report_only>0</report_only>
                         <report_uri>https://vendor.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
                    </storefront>
                    <admin>
                         <report_only>0</report_only>
                         <report_uri>https://vendor.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
                    </admin>
               </mode>

          </csp>
     </default>
</config>
```

`csp_whitelist.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
     <policies>
          <policy id="script-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                    <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="style-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="img-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                    <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="connect-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="font-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                    <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                    <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>

          <policy id="frame-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>

          <policy id="form-action">
               <values>
                    <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
     </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

#### Questions:

- What am I missing here, as inline styles (local and `elfsight.com` stuff are reported)
- **What is 'report-sample' here? I do not see any information anywhere**
- All the local inline-style errors, what do I do here ? The Theme we use are using so many inline styles (calculated from Javascript).
- Are there any 'default' values that does not apply if you create a custom `csp_whitelist.xml`?
- How do I even confirm if it is using my `csp_whitelist.xml`, as mentioned `report-only=0 or report-only=1` gives the same `[Report Only]` message in the console, and it doesn't feel like `report-only=0` enforces anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out it was a Chrome extension installed a few weeks ago (which I kind of have forgotten about).

The name is 'Content Security Policy (CSP) Generator', which never indicated **where it 'generates' the entries, but** this extension reports **all items, even if it works** and appends 'report-sample' which completely confused me as to origin of this.

Disabling the extension gave me a 100% clearer picture of *which items didn't have CSP entries*.

> For reference, a working setup I created of config and whitelist below.

> `config.xml` - **Here is how to use report_only=0 (enforce), but more importantly, fix for `frame-ancestors` which does not allow `unsafe-inline` in browsers (as of November 2021).**

- `frame-ancestors` fix is only currently applied in `2.4-develop` branch.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
     <default>
          <csp>
               <policies>
                    <storefront>
                         <frame-ancestors>
                              <inline>0</inline>
                         </frame-ancestors>
                    </storefront>
                    <admin>
                         <frame-ancestors>
                              <inline>0</inline>
                         </frame-ancestors>
                    </admin>
               </policies>
               <mode>
                    <storefront>
                         <report_only>0</report_only>
                         <report_uri>https://site.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
                    </storefront>
                    <admin>
                         <report_only>0</report_only>
                         <report_uri>https://site.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
                    </admin>
               </mode>

          </csp>
     </default>
</config>
```

`csp_whitelist.xml`

> - **I decided to name (`id`) them like this :`wildcard.`, because there are some rare instances where *non-wildcard domains (like elfsight.com)* rule do not work with them, so for instance 'img-src' I have two entries : 'elfsight.com' and 'wildcard.elfsight.com', two rules needed.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
     <policies>
          <policy id="script-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="style-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="img-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="elfsight.com" type="host">elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="connect-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="font-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>

          <policy id="frame-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>

          <policy id="form-action">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
     </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Edit config.xml:

> ```
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
>      <default>
>           <csp>
>                <policies>
>                     <storefront>
>                          <frame-ancestors>
>                               <inline>0</inline>
>                          </frame-ancestors>
>                     </storefront>
>                     <admin>
>                          <frame-ancestors>
>                               <inline>0</inline>
>                          </frame-ancestors>
>                     </admin>
>                </policies>
>                <mode>
>                     <storefront>
>                          <report_only>0</report_only>
>                          <report_uri>https://site.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
>                     </storefront>
>                     <admin>
>                          <report_only>0</report_only>
>                          <report_uri>https://site.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce</report_uri>
>                     </admin>
>                </mode>
>
>           </csp>
>      </default> </config>
> ```

- Edit csp_whitelist.xml

```
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
     <policies>
          <policy id="script-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="style-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="img-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="elfsight.com" type="host">elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="connect-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.sharethis.com" type="host">*.sharethis.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.elfsight.com" type="host">*.elfsight.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
          <policy id="font-src">
               <values>
                    <value id="wildcard.cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                    <value id="wildcard.googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
               </values>
          </policy>
```